# Swift - Detail View Controller depending on Table View Cell

Tags: xcode, swift, controller, tableview, uitableview

i have a basic table view controller with dynamic prototypes,

there can appear 4 cells, but there also can appear 6 cells.

What i want is:

Depending on which cell is clicked to switch to another "detail"-ViewController.

my first thought is like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if cell1clicked {
        // go to viewcontrollerA
    } elseif cell2clicked {
        // go to viewcontrollerB
    } elseif cell3clicked {
        // go to viewcontrollerC
    } else {
        // go to viewcontrollerD
    }

}
```

is this even possible with tableviewcontrollers?

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should work :)

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to do it by using `TableViewController` in storyboard and use static cells instead of dynamic.

Here is the way:

> 1- Define 4 cells in your static tableView.
>
> 2- Drag 4 View Controller in storyboard.
>
> 3- Connect First Cell with viewcontrollerA and so on in Storyboard.
>
> 4- Be sure that you subclass your class UITableViewController and remove tableview methods.

**Update :**

If you want to use dynamic cells its possible to push the `ViewController` programmatically :

> 1- Drag 4 ViewControllers and go to identity inspector and give each
>   one a Storyboard ID.
>
> 2- Create 4 classes for your ViewControllers and connect each
>   storyboard with its class.
>
> 2- Add Navigation Controller to your initial ViewController in
>   storyboard.

Ive made you a sample class here :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


    var array = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth"]


    @IBOutlet weak var tableviewmy: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

        return cell;
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            var controller1 : FirstViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerA") as! FirstViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)

        }else if indexPath.row == 1{
            var controller2 : SecondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerB") as! SecondViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller2, animated: true)
        }else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            // controller 3
        }else {    
            // controller 4
        }

    }

}
```

You may download a sample project :
https://yadi.sk/d/F5Qb85MLiMPqk

Comment: hey thanks fpr your answer, i added a table view in my initial view controller and created a custom cell with style: "basic". But the table view is still empty ? you could reference to this?

Comment: Custom cell doesn't work with basic style, you have to change it a custom style, ill upload a sample to show you.Please check my answer and download the sample , @Creativecrypter

Comment: let me know if it works, then you may accept it :) @Creativecrypter